# Is the FSA for that language right? Comparison between two solutions

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata

Given the alphabet $ Λ = \{a, b\}$ construct a FSA for the following language:

$$ L=\{α∈Λ^* ∧ |α|a =even ∧ |α|b =odd\}$$

where $|α|x $ is the number of occurrences of $x$ in $α$.
Basically, only strings where the number of $a$'s is even and the one of $b$'s is odd.

My attempt was the following:

[image]

whereas that's the solution of my teacher:

[image]

I wonder if mine is correct, too. I tried to follow the paths and I think that mine is working.

Comment: Your solution doesn't accept $aba$, but does accept $aa$. I suspect you don't understand the definition of the language.

Answer (score 1):

Your FSA would not accept the string `AAB` or `ABBBA`, or any string ending with a `B` or starting with `AB...` or starting with `BA...` etc., all of which it should.

One of your main issue is that you don't have any `B` paths out of state `1`, but more problematically you only have three states, when you need at least four. This is because you have 4 different possible states, so you need at least 4 states to store all of them (odd `A` & odd `B`, odd `A` & even `B`, even `A` & odd `B`, even `A` & even `B`).

Your teacher's is correct because it has essentially divided up the responsibility of checking the parity of `A`'s and `B`'s to different halves. That is, you're in the top half of the graph whenever the number of `A`'s is even, and the right half of the graph whenever the number of `B`'s is odd. This works because each additional letter added is going to either make `B` go from odd to even (or vice versa) or `A` to go from odd to even (or vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

Any NFA for your language contains at least 4 states, as we can show using the fooling set method. Consider the follows 4 pairs of words:
$$
(b,\epsilon),(\epsilon,b),(ab,a),(a,ab).
$$
For each pair $(x,y)$ we have $xy \in L$, while for every two different pairs $(x,y),(x',y')$ we have $x'y \notin L$.

Fix an NFA for $L$. For a pair $(x,y)$, choose an accepting computation, and denote by $q_x$ the state after reading $x$. I claim that $q_x \neq q_{x'}$ for different pairs $(x,y),(x',y')$. Indeed, since $xy \in L$, upon reading $y$ the NFA can reach from $q_x$ to an accepting state. If $q_{x'} = q_x$ that would imply that $x'y \in L$, contrary to fact.

It follows that any NFA for $L$ contains at least 4 different states.